# Shares files folder between two web servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, filesystems

I am implementing a C# (.NET) application in which user can upload files and images due to huge size (more than 80 gb) we are storing these files on file system now I am preparing a another web server which need to access those files.

My question is How can I access files from IIS from another server, both servers are on same network sharing folder does not solve problem for me

I read about using virtual folder but I have concern will it put extra load on IIS for handling user requests ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If it's on the same network, just access it via a network share. Using a virtual directory can be helpful, if for example you'd like to change the network location without having to change any code that references the location. The virtual directory itself won't put any extra strain on the IIS.

Local network speed will be your only bottleneck compared to files stored on the same machine as the IIS as far as I can tell, since you will be transferring the files first on your local network from one machine to the IIS machine, and then to the end user.

Comment: I am trying to use shared folder but i am getting access denied error when i try to access any file inside that shared folder, how can i give rights to IIS user to that folder since i can not give rights of 1 server user on other server's folder

Comment: Ok, sorry - I didn't realize that this was mainly a security settings issue.
Depending on what the security requirements are for the server that stores the files, you COULD just grant access to "Everyone" on the folder where the files are stored. If nothing else, doing so could be interesting just to test whether it all works as intended then.

Otherwise, youll need to figure out which user is actively accessing the file server when access is being made from the IIS. This page has some information on similar issues:
http://forums.iis.net/t/1157234.aspx?IIS+7+Virtual+Directory+to+Other+Server